# cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'LinearLayout'

Tags: android, xml, netbeans, android-linearlayout

I am using xml to define my UI for an Android app using Netbeans (7.1).  My main.xml looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Layout01"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/to (phone #)"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/date"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/subject"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/event description"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/send"
        />   

</LinearLayout>
```

When I attempt to validate my the xml (file) I receive "cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'LinearLayout'".  Also, my Java class (MainActivity) now shows an error indicating that it can't find the R.Layout.main class.  I've searched the internet far and wide with no luck.  Can someone please help?  Thanks,

Comment: throw another layout in there from a sample app and tell us what it does?  Also make sure you are using the right XML editor to edit it.

Comment: Have you tried to Clean` the project?

Comment: Try just creating a Hello World Android project.  I bet you see the same error. Test your setup first of all.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the file in Eclipse and there is nothing wrong with it. (Another solution is to switch to eclipse!)  This means your project is not setup correctly in Netbeans.  you need to tell netbeans where the Android SDK is located on your machine.  This should be a project setting and or recreate this as an Android project.  If its already an Android project check project settings for SDK. Because it cannot find Android SDK it cannot resolve the xml schema for the layouts.  Thats the problem, nothing wrong with your layout.  Never mind the R problem that will go away when you fix the configuration telling Netbeans about Android SDK.

Below is the problem and solution:

See: http://binarywasteland.com/2011/07/install-netbeans-android-sdk/

> Update
>
> It has been determined people were having trouble getting the NetBeans and Android SDK combo to work and it is because one key issue wasn’t mentioned.  When we download the Android SDK we need to add the SDK to a directory that will not have any spaces.  After this is done we need to add that directory to the System Variables under Path. To do this we need to click the start menu, navigate to computer, right click it and pick properties. You then need to click Advanced System Setting on the right hand side of the screen. You will then be presented with the following screen:

Comment: If thats not it, then you have not setup netbeans to recognize android or failed to create this as an Android project.

Comment: The OP tried to format the code block using the `` characters I've removed them now. I don't think they're in the orginal XML as there would be a totally different error.

Comment: Well I ran the file in eclipse and their is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

> When I attempt to validate my the xml (file) I receive "cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'LinearLayout'"

How did you attempt to validate it? This error generally means that the schema validator (probably Xerces) did not have access to the schema, for some reason connected with the way that the validator was invoked.